# LinkedList in Objective C will object be released?

Tags: objective-c, algorithm, linked-list

I am making a delete method in a `linked list` in `Objective C`. I want to delete a node in the list, however, in my delete code, I set the "head" element's "next" to the node to be deleted's "next". Will this cause the node to be deleted to NOT be freed from memory? If so, how to fix?

The list node is as follows

```
@interface ListNode : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, assign) int data;
@property (nonatomic, strong) ListNode* next;
@end
```

The code to delete is below.

```
-(BOOL)deleteElementWithHead:(ListNode*)headNode andNodeToDelete:(ListNode*)deleteNode{

    if (!head || !deleteNode) {
        return FALSE;
    }
    ListNode *element = head;

    if (deleteNode == head) {
        ListNode *temp;
    temp = element.next;
    head = nil;
    head = temp;
    return TRUE;
    }

    while (element) {
        if (element.next == deleteNode) {
            element.next = deleteNode.next;//set the pointer for element to the node to delete's "next" property so it points to the next one in the list
            deleteNode = nil;
            return TRUE;
        }
        element = element.next;
    }

    return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: ARC takes care of releasing the objects. As long as you don't have a reference cycle, you're fine. Yeah ARC!

Comment: BTW - setting `deleteNode` to `nil` is pointless.

Comment: so what would happen to the `deleteNode` - nothing references it, just it's property

Comment: If nothing references it then it will be released and deallocated.